# How to put jquery response data in modal using $.each

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have get response data in jquery i want to put this data in modal

```
if(response.status == 200){
  $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {                                     
  $('#eve_id').val(response.data[k].event_id);                                   
  $('#modal_image').val(response.data[k].event_image);                                       
  $('#modal_content').val(response.data[k].event_category);                                  
  $('#eve_category').val(response.data[k].event_content);
});
}
```

Modal body

```
<div class="modal-body" >
<div class="item active">
 <div id="eve_id"></div>
<div id="modal_image"></div>
<div id="modal_content" class="events-description"></div>
<div id="eve_category"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Since you're using `<div>` tags you want to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to begin with. `val()` only works for input fields.

Comment: divs don't have a `value` property, use `.html()` or `.text()` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments indicate, divs have no `value` property, you have to use either `.text()` or `.html()`

```
if(response.status == 200){
    $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {                                     
    $('#eve_id').text(v.event_id);                                   
    $('#modal_image').text(v.event_image);                                       
    $('#modal_content').text(v.event_category);                                  
    $('#eve_category').text(v.event_content);
  });
}
```

PS: you can you use the second parameter `v` which stand for the value of the current element.